# Should I edit an answer with misinformation or just write a new answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

My [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31120/8927) has received one answer with misinformation in it.  I have spent a bit of time doing my own research, and have come to same conclusion as the answer, but I can't bring myself to accept the answer as it is.

Is it better for me to edit the existing answer, removing the misinformation and possibly changing it quite a bit, or should I rather make a new answer even though it will be the same in essence?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think a second answer would be the same in essence.  The existing one reached its conclusion incorrectly, and it didn't answer your question satisfactorily.

Go ahead and post your answer.  To keep it complete, I'd be sure to:

- Mention "credit only".
- Mention why Stan found the mismatch.
- Explain why Stan's answer wasn't acceptable to *you*, the person who chooses the correct answer.

However, I'd suggest a little more searching first.  You said in the comment that Deanna Troi was listed as "credit only" in 10 episodes; [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deanna_Troi#Appearances) seems to disagree, listing which *8* episodes she did not appear in.  It seems odd that both the list of episodes and the list of "credit only" episodes are off by 2...

While this isn't an ideal situation, [it does happen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18041/pen-servo-in-tos-assignment-earth-the-doctors-sonic-screwdriver).

Comment: This is exactly how you should go about it on an StackExchange site.  If the answer is not right in it's entirety and you have the right answer, then post your own answer.  If that answer helped you reach you conclusion then credit them and upvote them, but do not mark as a correct answer as others will come along and assume it as completely correct.